# I am not able to apply if loop to a dataframe in r programming

Tags: r

I have a Blood pressure Dataframe with the below data.

```
   Name Age M.F Blood.Pressure
1     A  40   M            110
2     B  55   F            112
3     C  51   M            144
4     D  14   M            134
5     E  48   M             90
6     F  78   M             85
7     G  21   F            135
8     H  59   M            150
9     I  32   F             98
.....
```

I need to check B.P. of each record and based on the values, I have to create a new column with the strings ("Low","Normal","High") corresponding to B.P.
I am using the below code to do that.

```
excel <- read.csv("SampleCSVFile.csv", header=T)
df1 <- data.frame(excel)
df1

for(i in length(df2$Blood.Pressure))
{
  if (df1$Blood.Pressure > 80 & df1$Blood.Pressure < 120)
  {
      df1$is.cond <- c("Low")
  }

  else if(df1$Blood.Pressure > 120 & df1$Blood.Pressure < 140)
  {
      df1$is.cond <- c("Normal")
  }
  else if(df1$Blood.Pressure > 140)
  {
      df1$is.cond <- c("High")
  }
}
df1
```

But this is the output that I am getting.

```
   Name Age M.F Blood.Pressure is.cond
1     A  40   M            110     Low
2     B  55   F            112     Low
3     C  51   M            144     Low
4     D  14   M            134     Low
5     E  48   M             90     Low
6     F  78   M             85     Low
7     G  21   F            135     Low
8     H  59   M            150     Low
9     I  32   F             98     Low
10    J  63   M            150     Low
```

It is not checking each row, it just checks the first Blood pressure value, and based on that it assigns the string to all the rows. can you please help ?

Comment: That's because you're not even using looping variable 'i' anywhere. And please read the policy of how to ask good questions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?

Comment: What does [tag:python] have to do with this?

Comment: Or Excel? Or CSV? Don't use tags just because they might be suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a cleaner solution :

```
df1$is.cond <- ifelse(df1$Blood.Pressure > 80 & df1$Blood.Pressure < 120, "Low",
          ifelse(df1$Blood.Pressure > 120 & df1$Blood.Pressure < 140, "Normal", 
             ifelse(df1$Blood.Pressure > 140, "High" , "None")))
```

Comment: I got this idea as soon as I posted this question. Anyway thanks for your suggestion!.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop. This is a vectorized way to do things:

```
# initialize column
df1$is.cond = NA_character_

df1$is.cond[df1$Blood.Pressure > 80 & df1$Blood.Pressure < 120] = "Low"
df1$is.cond[df1$Blood.Pressure > 120 & df1$Blood.Pressure < 140] = "Normal"
df1$is.cond[df1$Blood.Pressure > 140] = "High"
```

However, for binning data like this the built-in function `cut` does all the work for us:

```
df1$is.cond.cut = cut(df1$Blood.Pressure,
                      breaks = c(-Inf, 80, 120, 140, Inf),
                      labels = c("unknown", "Low", "Normal", "High"))
```

In your method (and in my first example), because you use `<` rather than `<=`, no value will be assigned to blood pressures exactly on the threshholds. You might want to change that. `cut` defaults to intervals that are "closed on the right", meaning that a value of 120 would be considered Low. You can change this behavior by giving it the argument `right = F`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

See if that's what you needed .

```
df1 <- read.csv("file_to_read.csv",T,"~")


for(i in 1:nrow(df1))
{
  if (df1$Blood.Pressure[i] > 80 & df1$Blood.Pressure[i] < 120)
  {
    df1$is.cond[i] <- c("Low")
  }

  else if(df1$Blood.Pressure[i] > 120 & df1$Blood.Pressure[i] < 140)
  {
    df1$is.cond[i] <- c("Normal")
  }
  else if(df1$Blood.Pressure[i] > 140)
  {
    df1$is.cond[i] <- c("High")
  }
}

> df1
  Name Age M.F Blood.Pressure is.cond
1    A  40   M            110     Low
2    B  55   F            112     Low
3    C  51   M            144    High
4    D  14   M            134  Normal
5    E  48   M             90     Low
6    F  78   M             85     Low
7    G  21   F            135  Normal
8    H  59   M            150    High
9    I  32   F             98     Low
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. This is what I wanted.